# Extracting content from a website with Regular Expressions

Tags: xml, regex, preg-match

Hi I'm just trying to get a hang of regular expressions, i have being trying to extract content from this website but i reckon i have a problem with my regexp, as i cannot add anything to the array.
Can anyone point me in the right direction, I reckon its just something small.

Thanks

```
<?php   
    $f1 = fopen("http://www.irishexaminer.com/","r");
    $document = fread($f1,100000);
    fclose($f1);
    $regexp = "%<p>(.+)</p><p>%";
    preg_match($regexp,$document,$getHeading);  
    echo "<br>" . $getHeading[1];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($getHeading);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried confirming that `$document` does actually contain the html?

Comment: Yes i just had another look and it does contain <p> tags such as: <p> THERE is no excuse for loyalist violence on the streets of Belfast.<p />

Comment: What exactly is the output of this script?

Comment: Also: You probably shouldn't be parsing HTML with Regular Expressions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on line 7

Comment: Much as it pains me, they're using very strange HTML syntax, and your regex is incorrect.  Try `"%<p>(.+?)<p /><p>%"`

Comment: Some people who are wizards with regular expressions insist on using them to parse HTML/XML, and they still get it wrong. If you're not a wizard with regular expressions, don't even attempt it. It's the wrong tool for the job. Use a proper parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THERE is no excuse for white space in the closing tag of p in your case.

```
<p> THERE is no excuse for loyalist violence on the streets of Belfast.<p /><p>
```

Regex to match

```
%<p>(.+)</\s*p><p>%
```

It would take a while to make a regex resilient enough for HTML. Take Frankies advice too.  Vest your effort into something less prone to failure. You can use [PHP HTML Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)